# How to mock a class within a function that I'm trying to test?

Tags: c++, constructor, mocking, googlemock

I am trying to test a function like below within Provider.cpp,

```
SomeType::Data Provider::getData()
{
    const Param param();
    SomeType wanted_data = SomeType::Data(Creator{}(param));
    return wanted_data;
}
```

But that Creator creation in getData() makes testing this function difficult.

FYI, Provider.h is like

```
class Provider {
    public:
        SomeType::Data getData();
    
        // constructor/destructor
        Provider(System& system);
        ~Provider();
    
    private:
        System& m_system;
};
```

While Creator has the following in Creator.h

```
class Creator {
    public:
        //operator function overload?
        virtual SomeType::Data operator()(Param param) {
            SomeType::Data data = ...;//create data
            return data;
        }

        // constructor/destructor
        Creator();
        virtual ~Creator(){};
};
```

I looked up for hours, and it seems like mocking a creation of an object within a function seems not possible. If I still wanna test this function and create an the DataCreator object whenever I call getData(), how can I get it done? (if it's possible...)

I read on google saying something like you can use pointer or reference in the constructor in such case, but I am not sure  what it means... :'(

Comment: Looks like you're using a concrete `Creator`, which won't allow you to use a derived class. You'll need to modify your source to take a `Creator*`, which will allow you to supply either `Creator` or your mocked class.

Comment: Looks like you are using *after the fact testing* (TAD, Test After Development), rather than *testing to guide development* (TDD, Test-Driven Development).  This is the point where you discover the implementation had blithely violated SOLID is not unit testable, and needs to be refactored to allow after-the-fact testing.  TDD puts pressure on the developer to embrace SOLID at the get-go, rather than having to refactor it in.

Comment: @GuyMarino could you elaborate it a little on "modify your source to take a Creator*"?

Comment: What is to test in the getData? It creates a default-constructed param and calls creator. I am firmly convinced that in the present form `getData` needs no unit test.

Comment: @user2465084, here's a pastebin with a simple class override scenario. You can replace `CreatorMock` with your mocked class from googlemock: https://pastebin.com/vJkMSRm6

Comment: @SergeyA I simplified this function a bit. The function has a few condition checks, and this object creation is expected to happen in a certain case. I wanna test all difference cases, and this one was painful due to the object creation inside its if.

Comment: @Eljay yes I'm seeing the problem now... hopefully next time I start writing code I start it the right way :( still learning c++ :)

Comment: Well, if the code is different, it is hard for me to say how it should be modified. Your creator here is also statically typed, so I am not sure what is the point of it's `operator()` being virtual. I am afraid, you have produced a snippet which is too stripped of actual detail to give you a useful advice. Also, TDD is overrated ;)

Comment: @SergeyA that virtual on operator was to mock it for Provider's test actually. So  while testing the provider's construction it wouldn't try to create the actual data of SomeType::Data.  I hoped this would get picked up on the fuction getData() test as well and return a mocked SomeType::Data... but it doesn't give me what I want like how it worked for the constructor test. :/

Comment: You can always pass the instance of creator into the function (as a reference to Creator base type).

Comment: Although I don't agree in general about TDD with SergeyA, I do find TDD and C++ a **painful** marriage.  C++ is not conducive to TDD, because TDD is not part of the core language, and because the lengthy edit-compile-run cycle compared to other TDD amenable languages.  If C++ had *design by contract* as part of the core language, that'd make 95% of TDD unnecessary.  I prefer [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest) unit testing framework for C++.

Comment: @SergeyA may I ask for a simple example? I get that you're suggesting to do getData(Creator* creator), but I'm not sure then how to creator->operator(objid) or what needs to be done within the Creator constructor.

Comment: Refactoring the code to do *inversion of control* and *dependency injection*.  Rather than having the concrete class hard-coded inside the routine, have the dependency passed into the method or constructor.  Then you can pass in a mock object for testing.  (Avoids the high coupling / low cohesion problem of the current code.)

Comment: @Eljay I need to say, my comment was only related to C family of languages. For something like duck-typing python, TDD is probably a must.

Comment: As for example, I do know how your current code is structured. Something like `SomeType::Data Provider::getData(const Creator& cr) { ... SomeType wanted_data = SomeType::Data(cr(param)) ... }`

Comment: @SergeyA • then we are in vehement agreement!  (I loved C# in VS with NCrunch and NUnit testing.  It was pure joy!  And I never would have believed it had I not tried it out for myself for 3 years.)

Comment: @SergeyA then when I call getData() (it's elsewhere), I create a Creator to pass into the function pameter? like ```Provider provider; provider.getData(Creator()); ? ```

Comment: @Eljay I wish i could understand what you guys are talking about... :'(

Comment: @user2465084 yes. But in all honesty, if you find this concept hard to grasp, you probably need to get back to language basics, as it looks like there are significant gaps in your foundation knowledge.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't trying to exclude you.  Testing is a good practice.  C++ is a hard language to do it in.  Can be done, takes a high level of forethought and discipline.  TDD is even harder to do in C++.  Because the "one minute cycle" breaks when an hour long compile-link step is in the middle.

Comment: And, to @Eljay point, a lot of things which might require a unit test in other languages, are going to present itself as hard compilation errors in C++.

Comment: @SergeyA i'm working on it now, will update again! thanks!